# How to delete a partition using fdisk?

Tags: twrp, gsi

I am trying to install a GSI that is 1.8GB and i need to re-partition the system partition to allow the img to be installed, i tried using fdisk /dev/block/mmcblk0 then i tried using the command "d", but all it says is Selected partition 1 and it doesn't allow me to choose the partition number, which is partition 26 in my case (userdata), please help!!

Comment: Can you list the partitions in fdisk? If not may be you have a very old fdisk version that does not GPT partition scheme.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have twrp 3.5.2 on my SM-T330NU does it support GPT partitioning? Tell me how can i delete partition if my twrp recovery supports GPT.

Comment: I just updated twrp from 3.5.2 to 3.7.0, but i still can't use fdisk to delete ther userdata partition, it tells me"No partition is defined yet!" what can i do know?!?!